# Binance API answers from the future

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

Im having a problem with Binance API - rest and websocket.
It happens very often to me that the request i sent to Binance API, will happen in the "future".

Example:

The request i send:

```
import time
import requests

symbol = "XRPUSDT"
res = requests.get(f"https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/ticker/bookTicker?symbol={symbol}").json()

ts = float(res['time'])/1000
print(time.time()-ts)

print(time.time(), ts, float(res['time']))
```

Results: -0.046105384826660156

```
-0.046105384826660156
1634990526.2358947 1634990526.282 1634990526282.0
```

The "time" variable from the response (according to https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#symbol-price-ticker) should be "// Transaction time".

How is it then possible that i send a request, get the answer and subtract

```
"now - transaction_time(which took place some x time ago)"
```

and get something below 0?

Comment: I can't reproduce the example. For me I get positive values as expected.

Comment: For me it depends, sometimes i get the positive some other time negative. I just can't find why it happens. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Check your system time against the Binance `time` endpoint ([docs](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#check-server-time), [link](https://api.binance.com/api/v3/time)), it's possible that your system time is few seconds off from theirs, which would result in the negative difference.

Comment: Thanks @PetrHejda for mentioning that problem, but unfortunately i think thats not the case. Comparing my system time and server time (using your link) results in difference up to 10 ms while in my post i showed that i get sometimes even -50ms in the future (the system time difference would have to overcome my server ping + server processing time). If of course. I understand everything well. Plus it happens that i get the right time, above 0. Regards